# ServiceWorker Prefetching with absolute URLs

Tags: service-worker, absolute-path

I have a service worker (used for caching resources) on my site at https://example.com with a scope of **/app-1**.

```
example.com
- /images/image.jpg
- /css/style.css
- /app1
```

What I know from documentation is that service worker cannot access `../images/image.jpg` or `../css/style.css` because it can access only subpaths of the scope.

I went boldly and added absolute paths to my service worker for it to cache:

```
var urlsToPrefetch = [
 './',
 'https://example.com/css/style.css',
 'https://example.com/images/image.jpg'
];
```

And that somehow works, so now Cache Storage shows:

```
https://example.com/app1
https://example.com/images/image.jpg
https://example.com/css/style.css
```

Exactly what it should. There are no errors whatsoever.

Can anyone, please, confirm that this approach is acceptable and explain why (considering scope restrictions).

Answer (score 3):

Slight confusion here by what Serivce Worker Scope really means. It is used to specify the subset of your content that you want the service worker to control, not fetch.

As in Service Worker is installed upon a page that is in scope, it is then perfectly able to fetch the resources in the URL and cache them. The only issue being if any of these resources that are out of scope are pages that you wish to nagivate to, the Service Worker will not be installed on that page so you best plan for that loss in functionality.

One last thing is that if you put the Service Worker file at the root of the project, all content under the app's origin will be in scope. So should you put the Service Worker file at the root, then "/images/image.jpg" will be in scope.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for this explanation, it does help me. I am unable to change the location of service worker because there will be multiple workers on the same domain, but for different scopes.